# how to compare installed programms on one pc with other performance issues

Tags: windows-7, windows, performance, performance-tuning

I have 2 laptops, both run Windows 7,identical configuration.

One of them how ever is running extremely slow it takes a very long time to start up and shutdown and also if I need to run a programm it takes to much time for the application to fire up.I scanned with antivirus and there was no problem found.
So I have decided to compare both the system as why one is running extremely slow.

How should go for it and what steps are involved.What things should I check is there any systematic tutorial for the same?

Answer (score 0):

There can be subtle difference in hardware between systems.  No two RAM modules or CPU's will perform the same even if they were manufactured in the same factory. One CPU might use power better or run cooler while RAM timming on one set of modules may be better than an identical set.

The same for motherboards.  There are quite a lot of variables here to try and find the issue.  You can have a look at [Benchmarking](http://www.passmark.com/) for software to test the 2 systems and then try and swop out the hardware that may be lacking in performance.

Comment: Minor differences between two "identical" pieces of hardware rarely cause such big performance difference (unless you overclock to the limits).